# Delete refresh listview in Android

Tags: android

I have created a list activty1 and an activity2. In the list activity the list is getting populated by the database,  on list item selected activity2 is getting called. In activity2 i am updating the values in mysql database. when i am calling back to list activity1 another list item is getting added rather than the list item which was pressed getting updated. The values in database tables are updating fine. Please suggest.

Here is my list activity

```
@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public class DocPresc extends ListActivity {

//public static Context ctx;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    String pid;
    JSONArray products = null;
    EditText ailm,date,comment;
    Button delete;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_patient_presc = "http://192.168.44.208/get_prescription.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
  //  private static final String TAG_PATIENT_ID = "patient_id";
    private static final String TAG_AIL = "ailment";
    private static final String TAG_MED = "medicine_name";
    private static final String TAG_D1 = "qty1";
    private static final String TAG_D2 = "qty2";
    private static final String TAG_D3 = "qty3";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "prescription_date";
    private static final String TAG_COM = "comment";
    private static final String TAG_DID = "dosage_id";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.docpresc);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
          .penaltyLog().build());

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        Intent i = getIntent();

         Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
         pid  = extras.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID");
         System.out.println("Docpresc"+pid);

         ailm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
         date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date1);
         comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comment1);


        // if (savedInstanceState == null) {

             new LoadPrescriptions().execute();
        //   }






    }





    class LoadPrescriptions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("patient_id",pid));//search1.getText().toString()));
             System.out.println("database"+pid);
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_patient_presc, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Patients: ", json.toString());


                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    //-----------------------------------
                    /*JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(0);

                    ailm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
                    ailm.setText(product.getString(TAG_AIL));*/
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String medicine = c.getString(TAG_MED).toUpperCase();
                        String qty1 = c.getString(TAG_D1).toUpperCase();
                        String qty2 = c.getString(TAG_D2).toUpperCase();
                        String qty3 = c.getString(TAG_D3).toUpperCase();
                        String dsg_id = c.getString(TAG_DID).toUpperCase();
                        //String ail = c.getString(TAG_AIL).toUpperCase();

                        ailm.setText(c.getString(TAG_AIL));
                        date.setText(c.getString(TAG_DATE));
                        comment.setText(c.getString(TAG_COM));


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value


                        map.put(TAG_MED, medicine);
                        map.put(TAG_D1,qty1);
                        map.put(TAG_D2,qty2);
                        map.put(TAG_D3,qty3);
                        map.put(TAG_DID,dsg_id);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);  


                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                   }
                   });
            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            //  pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    //ListAdapter 
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DocPresc.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item2, new String[] {
                                TAG_MED,TAG_D1,TAG_D2,TAG_D3,TAG_DID},
                                new int[] {R.id.med,R.id.d1,R.id.d2,R.id.d3,R.id.did });
                    // updating listview
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);

                    setListAdapter(adapter);



                }

             });

        }

    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

    //menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
    //menuSearch.setVisible(false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}






    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           // handle item selection

           switch (item.getItemId()) {

              case R.id.add:

                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID",pid );
                System.out.println("bundle"+pid);
                Intent i = new Intent(DocPresc.this,AddPresc.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(i,100);

                 return true;

              default:

                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

          }

        }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //onAttach(getActivity());
        //lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        String did1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.did)).getText().toString();
        String med1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.med)).getText().toString();
        String dg1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d1)).getText().toString();
        String dg2 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d2)).getText().toString();
        String dg3 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d3)).getText().toString();

    //  System.out.println("all  patient"+id1);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID",did1 );
        bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID1",med1 );
        bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID2",dg1 );
        bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID3",dg2 );
        bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID4",dg3 );


        //  System.out.println("bundle"+id1);
        Intent i = new Intent(DocPresc.this,EditPresc.class);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivityForResult(i,100);




        //passData(date);


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            /*Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);*/
       // ((SimpleAdapter)getListAdapter())
     //   ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            //getListView().setAdapter(null);
            //getListView().refreshDrawableState();
            new LoadPrescriptions().execute();
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }
```

}

Here is the activity getting called on list item pressed

```
public class EditPresc extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

//public static Context ctx;

    EditText medicine;
    EditText dosage1;
    EditText dosage2;
    EditText dosage3;
    Button edit;
    ImageButton up1 , up2,up3;
    ImageButton down1,down2,down3;
    String did,medi,q1,q2,q3;
    int count = 1;
    //JSONArray products = null;




    //int pid = "100";


    //private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
  //  private static final String url_getdosage = "http://192.168.44.208/get_dosage.php";
    private static final String url_updatedosage = "http://192.168.44.208/update_dosage.php";
    private static final String url_getmedname = "http://192.168.44.208/getmedname.php";



    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
  //  private static final String TAG_PATIENT_ID = "patient_id";


    private static final String TAG_MED_ID ="medicine_id";


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editpresc);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
          .penaltyLog().build());

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        Intent i = getIntent();

         Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
         did  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID");
         medi  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID1");
         q1  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID2");
         q2  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID3");
         q3  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID4");

         medicine = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.atxt1);
         dosage1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
         dosage2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
         dosage3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text3);

         medicine.setText(medi);
         dosage1.setText(q1);
         dosage2.setText(q2);
         dosage3.setText(q3);






         System.out.println("Editpresc"+did);

        //send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        up1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.up1);
     down1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.down1);
     dosage1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    up2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.up2);
     down2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.down2);
     dosage2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    up3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.up3);
     down3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.down3);
     dosage3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text3);
     //dosage1.setText("1");
     up1.setOnClickListener(this);
     up2.setOnClickListener(this);
    up3.setOnClickListener(this);
    down1.setOnClickListener(this);
    down2.setOnClickListener(this);
    down3.setOnClickListener(this);
    //ailment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.atxt);

    //comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ctxt);
    //presc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.presc_id);
    edit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

   //   new GetDosage().execute();



    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new GetMedname().execute();
             new EditDosageDetails().execute();

        }
    });




    }

    private class GetMedname extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        //  JSONObject product;

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag

                    int success;
                    try {

                        String med1 = medicine.getText().toString();
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medicine_name",med1));//search1.getText().toString()));

                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_getmedname, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                             if(product!= null){



                                 // display product data in EditText
                                 medicine.setText(product.getString(TAG_MED_ID));

                             }

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
                    //return product;
             return null;

        }

    }
```

private class EditDosageDetails extends AsyncTask {
        //  JSONObject product;

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        //JSONObject product = null;
        //id.setText(100);
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {


               String med = medicine.getText().toString();
               System.out.println("editdosage"+med);
               String do1 = dosage1.getText().toString();
               String do2 = dosage2.getText().toString();
               String do3 = dosage3.getText().toString();
               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medicine_id", med));

               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dosage_id", did));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty1", do1));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty2", do2));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty3", do3));

                   JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_updatedosage,
                           "POST", params);
                    // json success tag
                  // Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                   // check for success tag
                   try {
                       int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                       if (success == 1) {
                           // successfully created product
                           Intent i = getIntent();
                           setResult(100,i);
                           finish();
                           // super.onBackPressed();
                           // closing this screen

                       } else {
                           // failed to create product
                       }
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
     //      }
           }

        });
                //return product;
         return null;

      //  });

       // return product;
    }

}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

    //menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
    //menuSearch.setVisible(false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.up1:
            int a=Integer.parseInt(dosage1.getText().toString());
            int b = a+1;
            dosage1.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
            break;

        case R.id.down1:
             a=Integer.parseInt(dosage1.getText().toString());
             b = a-1;
            dosage1.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
            break;

        case R.id.up2:
             a=Integer.parseInt(dosage2.getText().toString());
             b = a+1;
            dosage2.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
            break;

        case R.id.down2:
            a=Integer.parseInt(dosage2.getText().toString());
             b = a-1;
           dosage2.setText(new Integer(b).toString());

        case R.id.up3:
            a=Integer.parseInt(dosage3.getText().toString());
             b = a+1;
           dosage3.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
           break;

        case R.id.down3:
            a=Integer.parseInt(dosage3.getText().toString());
             b = a-1;
           dosage3.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
           break;
        //case R.id.save:
        //  System.out.println("save pressed");



        }


    }
```

}

Comment: can you please clarify your question?

Comment: what i basically want is to implement edit functionality on list item. I am updating the table in database when list item is pressed. after updating the db in editpresc class when i am calling back the list activity , the list is getting refreshed but its not updating the list item , its adding a new item to the list. So i want to clear the list first and then refresh it. As i am using arraylist , i am not able to use clear().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)make arraylist null

2)initialize arraylist

3)fill arraylist with your content

4)pass this arraylist to list